# parameter 1 is not of type 'SVGRect'

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm trying to call native SVG functions, but the browser is complaining that my `rect` parameter is not an `SVGRect`. I'm not sure there's any difference, `SVGRect` seems to be an interface, but shouldn't it still accept a `rect` node?

**HTML**:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="884" style="opacity: 1;">
<rect class="overlay" width="1920" height="884"></rect>
</svg>
```

**JS**:

Creation:

```
var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append("svg")
            .attr('xmlns',d3.ns.prefix.svg)
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height",height)

    svg.append('svg:rect')
        .attr('class','overlay')
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height",height)
```

Later:

```
var svg = d3.select('svg').node()
var rect = d3.select('rect.overlay').node();
var intersect = svg.checkIntersection(this,rect)
```

Above code throws error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getEnclosureList' on 'SVGSVGElement': parameter 1 is not of type 'SVGRect'.`

Comment: an SVGRect and a rect element are completely different things. The former is cannot be rendered it's a data holder only, the latter is a markup object which is rendered. You can't mix use one when an API expects the other.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How do i obtain a reference to an `SVGRect` object that reflects my `rect` element's properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you can use the bounding box... it's not very clear in the official docs, or maybe I just don't understand the language enough.

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__checkIntersection

`var intersect = svg.checkIntersection(this,rect.getBBox())`

Gives me the result i need.